# MySQL Table Joining With AVG()

Tags: mysql

I have a "ratings" table, that contains (as a foreign key) the ID for the thing that it is rating. There are possibly multiple ratings for a thing, or no ratings for a value.

I want to join tables to see the different ratings for all the different IDs, but right now I'm having trouble viewing things that have no ratings. For example:

```
mysql> select avg(ratings.rating), thing.id from ratings, things where ratings.thingId = thing.id group by thing.id;
+----------------------+----+
|  avg(ratings.rating) | id |
+----------------------+----+
|               6.3333 |  1 |
|               6.0000 |  2 |
+----------------------+----+
```

Is there any way to modify my select query to also include IDs that have no ratings? I tried modifying the statement to say `where ratings.thingId = thing.id or thing.id > 0` but that doesn't seem to help.

Thanks and sorry if it's unclear.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
SELECT  AVG(ratings.rating),
        thing.id
    FROM things
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ratings
            ON ratings.thingId = things.id
    GROUP BY thing.id
```

Answer (score 5):

You're currently performing an INNER JOIN, which eliminates `things` records with no associated `ratings`. Instead, an OUTER JOIN...

```
SELECT AVG(COALESCE(ratings.rating, 0)), thing.id 
FROM things
LEFT JOIN ratings ON things.id = ratings.thingId
GROUP BY thing.id
```

Will return ALL `things`, regardless of whether or not they have `ratings`. Note the use of `COALESCE()`, which will return the first non-NULL argument - thus `things` with no `ratings` will return 0 as their average.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - hadn't gotten that far in my book yet and was really wondering how to solve this problem!

Answer (score -1):

SELECT p.id,p.title,(select round(avg(pr.rating),1)
from post_rating pr 
where pr.postid=p.id)as AVG FROM `posts` p